# Can we remember the user outside a route in passport.js?

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication, passport.js, mean-stack

I'm creating a MEAN Stack food catalog application. Node.js gives me the user logged in, in my login route when I check for req.isAuthenticated(). But when I try to check later whether I'm still logged in, it gives req.user as undefined.

How do I make the user persist? I know I can use local storage but is there a better way?

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose'); 

app = express();
app.use(require('express-session')({secret:"timelord",resave:false,saveUninitialized:false}));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/delectabledb');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({name: String,
gender: String,
dob: String,
country:String,
phone: String,
email: String,
password: String,
username: String,
prof: String});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
var User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.post('/loginUser', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
      console.log(req.user) //returns false
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      if (!user) { res.send({code:"500"}); }
      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        console.log(req.user) //returns true
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        res.send({code:"200", user:user});
      });
    })(req, res, next);
  });

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log("Running server on port 3000...");
});
```

Comment: If the `req.user` is undefined maybe you don't add the `JWT` to the request (from the client-side) or your `passport-js` callback is missing something (please add code snippet).

Comment: @Daniel, thanks for the reply. I've added the code snippet. So, in the loginUser route, it prints false and then true which is expected. If I again hit the route to login, shouldn't it print true and true becase I've already logged in?